# function that runs all the time in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to make a function that is always running in xcode similar to Unity's "function Update()". is this possible and if so, how.

Comment: In Xcode or in your program? For which language?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - are you talking about iPhone/iPad or Mac OS X ? And what programming language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read up on [run loops](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?RunLoop) and [NSTimers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me,Hope it will help you!

write this function in your viewDidLoad() method

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(onTick:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

And Here is the onTick: Method do whatever you want to run all the time

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
  {

  //do something here

  }
```